# Add multiple query results to array

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to run 4 queries from my parse database, each pulling just 1 object. I am trying to add each of the objects to an array that can then be used in a collection view. The queries run successfully but the app crashes because it is pulling null values. Here is my code:

```
var query1desc = ""
var query2desc = ""
var descs = [String]()

fileprivate func fetchUsers() {

        let query1 = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
        query1.limit = 1
        query1.findObjectsInBackground{
            (objects, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if objects?.count == 0 {
                 } else {
                    let object = objects![0] as! PFObject
                    self.query1desc = object["message"] as! String
                }

            }
        }
            let query2 = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
            query2.limit = 1
            query2.findObjectsInBackground{
                (objects, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if objects?.count == 0 {
                       } else {
                       let object = objects![0] as! PFObject
                       self.query2desc = object["message"] as! String
                    }
                 }
            }

self.descs = [self.query1desc, self.query2desc]
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

Does anyone know of a way to fix this so that self.descs does not just provide nil values? When I print within the query itself I know that objects are being pulled. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The queries complete in the background, so you can't access `self.query1desc` and `self.query2desc` there.  You need to access them in the completion blocks, or perhaps use a `dispatch_group` and `dispatch_group_notify`

Comment: Isn't (objects, error) -> Void in the completion block?

Comment: Yes, but the last two lines will be executed before the completion block has executed, so those properties will be nil.

Answer (score 0):

I think desc variable holds nil value because your program is executing an array assignment code part while completion handlers are still processing query requests. You need to wait until all your query requests finish and then can collect all the results.

```
let workGroup = DispatchGroup()

let queueForQuery1 = DispatchQueue(label: "firstQuery")
let query1 = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
query1.limit = 1

workGroup.enter()

queueForQuery1.async(group:workGroup) { 

    query1.findObjectsInBackground{ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            if objects?.count == 0 {
            } else {
                let object = objects![0] as! PFObject
                self.query1desc = object["message"] as! String
             }
       }
       workGroup.leave()
    }
}

let queueForQuery2 = DispatchQueue(label: "secondQuery")
let query2 = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
query2.limit = 1

workGroup.enter()


queueForQuery2.async(group:workGroup) { 

    query2.findObjectsInBackground{ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            if objects?.count == 0 {
            } else {
                let object = objects![0] as! PFObject
                self.query1desc = object["message"] as! String
             }
       }
       workGroup.leave()
    }
}

workGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main){
    self.descs = [self.query1desc, self.query2desc]
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I am having a hard time because it does not work with Swift 3. This is the only section giving me problems. DispatchGroup.notify(queue: workGroup){
            self.descs = [self.query1desc, self.query2desc]
            self.carouselView.reloadData()
        }

Comment: I updated my answer. I haven't written gcd code in Swift 3 but I just tried to convert it.